# Debugging School Project

Tags: java

Right, I am working on a program for school the purpose of the program is to find the minimum number of coins, I am a novice programmer and this is my first time so I dont know the thousands of other things and what not other people do. I wrote the code and it works, but I seem to have found a bug/glitch or w/e you want to call it.

my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coin {

public static void main (String[] Args) {

    int quarters = 25;
    int dimes = 10;
    int nickles = 5;
    int pennies = 1;


    System.out.println("Enter in a number between 1-99");

    // "Input" Part of Code (Remember this and go back for reference)
    Scanner Userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

   int stuff = Userinput.nextInt();
   int q = stuff/quarters;
   String A = "Number of Quarters:" +q;


   System.out.println(A);

   int hold = stuff%quarters;
   int d = hold/dimes;
   String B = "Number of Dimes:" +d;

   System.out.println(B);

   int hold1 = stuff%dimes;
   int n = hold1/nickles;
   String C = "Number of Nickles:" +n;

   System.out.println(C);

   int hold2 = stuff%nickles;
   int p = hold2/pennies;
   String D = "Number of Pennies:" +p;

   System.out.println(D);

   System.out.println("Thank you for Using My Program");

      }
}
```

Now, everything works fine I can input any number I like and get the desired result, however for some odd reason I cannot fathom I type in any number between 75-79 and there is an added Nickle for some odd reason and I have spent the better part of 2 hours trying to figure out exactly what is wrong but cannot. Hav tried dozens of toher numbers and they work fine except for that one little area.

Can someone tell me by chance what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `hold = ...` lines should be based on the previous `hold` value rather than the full amount (`stuff`).

```
int hold2 = hold%nickles;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subtract off what has already been accounted for when adding previous, larger coins.

For example, if I say 77, then the program will check 77%10 and return 7.  You would want to adjust your "stuff" value by any previously added coins.  So in this case, after adding 3 quarters (75) we would want to set stuff = stuff - 75 (stuff -= 75).

EDIT: to be more precise, after every calculation you could run

```
stuff -= q * quarters;
```

of course, changing the variables to be appropriate for each part of your code.

Comment: You are epic m8, thank you very much ^_^ you have saved me from a night of horrid stress lol *bows

Comment: Not a problem, if my answer helped you and was your preferred solution, I'd appreciate you marking this as the accepted answer :)